# The "mkdir" command in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, mkdir

I'm working on "The Command Line Crash Course", and when I try to run "mkdir temp" in PowerShell (Windows) I get something like "Access to the path is denied", and according to the book http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html I'm supposed to get something really different. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be possibly due to the Access permissions. Try running as an `Administrator`

You can also use the [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) to resolve your purpose.Something like this:-

```
runas /user:computername\useraccount mkdir thedirtomake\somesubdir\
```

OR

You can create the directory somewhere where you have write access

Comment: Running as administrator is not such a good advice. Nada should simply create the directory somewhere where he/she has write access.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- That is probably a good alternative too. I faced a similar situation in the past so I recommend that.!!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Updated my answer with your suggestion :)